# What are expected values for fulfillment_status in orders API

Tags: shopify

The [documentation](http://api.shopify.com/order.html) only mentions possible values for the `fulfillment_status` *filters*, which appear to be different from what the `fulfillment_status` values will be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Legal values are as follows:

- `nil` - The start state, which can transition to any of the following

  - `restocked` - Order has been cancelled and line-items have been restocked
  - `partial` - Some, but not all, of this order's line items have been fulfilled
  - `fulfilled` - All line items have been fulfilled

Comment: Thanks David.  Actually, `null` is the initial expected value, no?

Comment: Actually I'm seeing a `fulfilled` value right now.  are you sure about these values?

Comment: Oops, you're right. Those are the statuses for the Fulfillment object. I'll edit my answer with the correct ones for Orders.

Comment: It seems like the status unfulfilled is working as well and return all the orders that the fulfillment status is Partial or null

Comment: I have never seen a line item with `restocked` status. Even after restocking via the Shopify Admin, this status is never shown on a line item.

Comment: This answer is wrong. The fulfillment_status query filter for orders doesn't recognize "fulfilled" (the correct value for that would be "shipped"). The answer by Arthur Noseda below is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Surprisingly, [Admin GraphQL API](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-graphql/2023-04/queries/orders) lacks this critical piece of information (at least I could not find it). However, [Admin REST API](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-rest/2023-04/resources/order#get-orders?status=any) has it.
As of may 2023, values for `fulfillment_status` are `shipped`, `partial`, `unshipped`, `any`, and `unfulfilled`.

Comment: This answer is the correct one. The top-rated answer from 2012 is obsolete.